# Parsing JSON in javascript coming from Java Jackson JSON

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson

I followed this example to generate a json string to be later parsed in javascript

```
package example;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        map.put("key1","value1");
        map.put("key2","value2");

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

in Javascript:

```
 $http.get('/rest/json-example').
            success(function(data) {
                //$scope.count = data.length;
                console.log(data.key1);
                //console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            }).error(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

I don't know how to parse the string, this is how it gets printed using

```
console.log(data)
// Object {key1: "value2", key2: "value1"}
```

If I use

```
JSON.parse(data); 
// I get an error "unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected token o at Object.parse (native)..."
```

if I try to access it like:

```
console.log(data[0]);
// I get undefined
```

Comment: Maybe the string `data` is not JSON because it didn't quote the property names? Where is `data` defined?

Comment: @JuanMendes: A JSON serializer will produce valid JSON.

Comment: @SLaks I would hope so, but the OP is calling `JSON.parse` on it and it's failing? The OP needs to show where data is defined.

Comment: thanks I added my javascript call

Comment: `data` has already been converted into a JavaScript object from JSON, no need to parse it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is an object with two properties.

`JSON.parse()` fails because it isn't a string of JSON.

`data[0]` doesn't return anything because it has no such property.

You want `data.key1`.

Comment: where is `data` coming from? Is it not a string from an AJAX call?

Comment: @JuanMendes: We have no idea, but `console.log` is clearly showing that it is an object.

Comment: That is true, I missed the `Object` in front of it, thought it could have been a problem with the JSON serializer. Some JSON serializers do have the option to not quote strings, or maybe that's just when deserializing...